# Is there a special mime type for sending mail content geared towards mobile phones

Tags: email, mobile

I've been writing mail software for years and now I'm being asked to deliver mail to mobile phones.
You can send a multipart/alternative type email so you can send both html and text versions of the email. Has there been a standard introduced that supports a 3rd type geared towards mobile devices?
I've been searching but I'm not finding anything.

I figure most new phones (read: at least android and ios) are advanced enough that they can display html mail fairly well, that they wouldn't need this, but I was wondering if there was an actual standard that maybe nobody's adopted yet.

Comment: Why should there be a new standard? What's wrong with `multipart`?

Comment: sorry, what I meant was in addition to text/plain and text/html is there a text/mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special mimetype for mobile phones.  Mobile phones just use the existing standard, and it is up to the phone itself how it displays it.

Answer (score 1):

You must not do anything special, just mobile phone must have installed a mail client and set correctly in order to receive mails.

I don't think that is a special mime just for mobile phone, just you will have to care what features mobile mail client support ( can display images?, can display a specific tag?, can handle javascript?, etc)